# Как отловить событие запуска любого приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Задача: нужно при запуске любого приложения выводить `Toast` с текстом "*такое-то приложение запустилось*", а когда приложение закрывается (через `finish()`, или кнопкой Назад — без разницы), вне зависимости от того, работают ли `Service` этого приложения, или нет, — опять же, показать `Toast` с текстом "*такое-то приложение завершилось*".

Например, запустил `Play Market` — получил `Toast`: "*Play маркет запутился*".

Как это реализовать? Кажется нужно использовать `Service`, а дальше никаких мыслей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) и отлавливать событие [TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED)

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    switch (accessibilityEvent.getEventType()) {
         case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
            if (accessibilityEvent.getPackageName() != null) {
               showToast("App "+accessibilityEvent.getPackageName()+" window state changed");
            }
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

По хорошему это не очень то и возможно, правда есть определенные хаки, с помощью которых можно отловить событие запуска приложения. В частности, в момент запуска приложения ОС выставляет логи, примерно следующего содержания:

> 05-17 13:55:30.586: I/ActivityManager(526): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.rovio.angrybirds/com.rovio.fusion.App} from pid 818

То есть вам надо ловить в логах запуск `Intent`'а `android.intent.action.MAIN` и извлечь пакет (как в данном случае `com.rovio.angrybirds`)

Для того, чтобы читать логи вам нужно иметь пермишен

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

и в сервисе читать логи *LogCat*:

```
  Process logcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcatProc.getInputStream()));
```

Дальше уже парсить полученный `StreamReader`

Как только вы отловите название стартовавшего пакета, то по имени пакета получить имя проги уже совсем просто:

```
final String packageName = "my.application.package"
PackageManager packageManager= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

Answer (score -2):

Нужно переопределить метод `finish()`, и в нем вызывать *Toast* и вызывать `finish()` суперкласса. Либо в методе `onFinish` вывести *Toast*.

Comment: Выводить `Toast` в моем приложении о том, что запустился "Play Market" и завершился

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?